# How could I unit test this?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am using the Mono and Lokad quality libraries to develop an API which does things like inspect the characteristics of methods to see if they throw exceptions, etc etc.

One of my methods I have in this API looks like this:

```
// Get all methods which have a NotImplementedException
var throwingMethods = _codebase.Methods
    .Where(m => m.GetInstructions()
                 .Exists(i => i.Creates<NotImplementedException>())
    ).ToArray();
 return throwingMethods;
```

How could I unit test this? C# does not have its own native ability to do the same thing. Perhaps I could just have a small assembly, make a hard-coded collection, and compare?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try mocking the `_codebase` variable to return some predefined methods for your unit test.

If `_codebase` is set by a variable passed to the constructor of the class you are testing (constructor injection) then this might be pretty easy (assuming of course that the `Methods` property is overridable and the class is not sealed).